# Swipe to delete cell without having to press delete button Swift

Tags: swift, swipe, delete-row, uitableview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

In Swift. How can I add a swipe to delete on cell (still showing the color and label of delete) but as the swipe is ended it does the delete action. I saw the same questioned answered elsewhere but was for objective c. I'm not sure if swift has any new implementation for this. Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Did you end up finding an answer?

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of these two methods other than the basic `UITableView` implementations :

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        objects.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    }
}
```

Comment: If im not mistaken, that code reveals the delete button, but the user still has to touch the delete button to delete it. I'm looking for what's in a lot of mail apps where you swipe and let go and the action is performed. Example. Google inbox. Swipe one way to archive. Swipe another to snooze. Or bigger/longer on X axis swipe to delete.  That make sense?